# Keras Python custom loss function to give the maximum value of (absolute difference of) Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have as my output a 1-D array of 5 elements, it looks like this in the model:

```
out_vector = Dense(out_count, activation='relu', name='out_vector')(network_layer_3)
```

where `out_count` is 5 (not that it really matters). When I compare it to `true_out_vector`, another 5D array, I want the loss to be the "maximum of the absolute differences of the elements".

Simple example what I mean:

```
v1 = [94, 1000, 50, 85, 23]

v2 = [100, 430, 88, 12, 90]
```

I want my loss to equal the biggest absolute difference, which is `|1000 - 430| = 570` clearly, since element 2 has this biggest difference. I'm having trouble making this happen in Keras. Here's what I've tried:

```
def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
        return K.maximum(K.abs(yTrue - yPred))
```

But I get the error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 609, in ndim
    dims = x.get_shape()._dims
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

I'm sure there should be a simple way to do what I'm going after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
from keras import backend as K
v1 = K.constant([94, 1000, 50, 85, 23])
v2 = K.constant([100, 430, 88, 12, 90])


def customLoss(yTrue, yPred):
    return K.max(K.abs(yTrue - yPred))

result = customLoss(v1, v2)

sess = K.get_session()
print(sess.run(result))
```

and the output is:

```
570.0
```

NB: The method `K.maximum` takes two tensors while you are passing only one

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I run my model I get the error `dims = x.get_shape()._dims
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`

Comment: edit - nvm that error seems to be coming from something else I'm doing. Thanks for your suggestion I believe it works.